# In Java SWT, i am trying to display few information in a seperate console. Is it possible to display list of items to be displayed in the console?

Tags: java, swt

```
propertyConsole.setText("\n Project Name:" + item1.projectName + ".act"
                                    + " " + "\n\n   Category:       " + item1.category + "  "
                                    + "\n\n Modules:               " + item1.modulesList[]);
```

In Java SWT, i am trying to display few information in a seperate console. Is it possible to display list of items to be displayed in the console?  The modulesList is actually a list of 4 or 5 items which need to be displayed in the console

Comment: What "console" - what is `propertyConsole`? Various controls do lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *[Arrays#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))* method to return a *String* representation of a given array.

Here is an example.

```java
String[] strings = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
```

Output

```
[abc, def, ghi]
```

Furthermore, you may find it useful to organize your *String* value by utilizing the *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* and *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* classes.

Additionally, the *Formatter* class *JavaDoc* provides the extensive set of format specifiers.
*[Formatter (Java SE 20 & JDK 20) – Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#conversions-heading)*.

```java
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(string);
formatter.format("Project Name: %s.act%n", item1.projectName);
formatter.format("Category:     %s%n", item1.category);
formatter.format("Modules:      %s", Arrays.toString(item1.modulesList));
formatter.flush();
propertyConsole.setText(string.toString());
```